# Selenium Select returns None after finding an element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

When running the following code on a specific website that contains the following dropdown list:

```
<div  class="wrapper-map-canvas" >
        <div class="searchResaller">

            <div class="background-searchResaller"></div> 
            <h3>Search to find your<br/>local vendor</h3>
            <select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers1(this.value);" class="select-country"  name="country"><option value="">Your Country name</option><option value="" selected >Choose your location</option><option value="Afghanistan"  >Afghanistan</option><option value="Angola"  >Angola</option><option value="Argentina"  >Argentina</option><option value="Australia"  >Australia</option><option value="Austria"  >Austria</option><option value="Bangladesh"  >Bangladesh</option><option value="Belgium"  >Belgium</option><option value="Bolivia"  >Bolivia</option><option value="Brazil"  >Brazil</option></select>            </div>
        <div class="resultResaller-wrap">
            <div id="resultResallers" class="resultResaller"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The code itself:

```
    def test(self):
    self.driver.get("https://...")
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            ExpectedCon.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "type")))

        print("Element is visible? " + str(element.is_displayed()))

        select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='country']"))
        print(select.select_by_visible_text("Angola"))
    finally:
        self.driver.quit()
```

The element is visible and I tried increasing the wait time, selecting by index and using the `find_element_by_name` method but still it prints None.

Comment: That selects the option with that option it's not really a print function.

Comment: Sorry mate I didnt understand the answer. Can you explain a bit more?